# What is the best jqGrid wrapper for ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I found some **MVC wrappers** for **jqGrid**. but could not choose one of them.
Because it seems that some advance features of **jqGrid** is not implemented by those wrappers.

Can you please tell me what is the best practice for using jqGrid.

What is the solution/project that is mostly used. Maybe there is a project that everyone are using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best wrapper : **[jqGrid MVC Html Helper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421189/jqGrid-MVC-Html-Helper)**

All of **jqGrid** features are supported by this Html helper. **[Ken C. Len](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=968290)** has done some nice modifications on **[trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)** jgGrid html helper.

trirand's html helper is not supporting **Search** and **Sub Grid** but **Ken C. Len** implemented these features to.

Thanks to [Ken C. Len](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=968290) and [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) for their good work.

This is a sample code to put inside your View :

```
@using Mvc.HtmlHelpers
@(
Html.jqGrid("AccountList")

// columns
.addColumn(new Column("AccountNumber").setLabel("AccountNumber").setWidth(100).setSortable(true))
.addColumn(new Column("AccountName").setLabel("AccountName").setWidth(250).setSortable(true).setEditable(true))
.addColumn(new Column("AccountDate").setLabel("Date").setWidth(70).setSortable(true))
.addColumn(new Column("AccountType").setLabel("Type").setWidth(80).setSortable(true))
.addColumn(new Column("AccountBalance").setLabel("Balance").setWidth(80).setSortable(true))

// settings
.setCaption("Account")
.setRequestType(RequestType.get)
.setUrl("~/Home/GetAccountList/")
.setAutoWidth(true)
.setHeight(400)
.setRowNum(10)
.setRowList(new int[]{10,15,20,50})
.setViewRecords(true)
.setSortName("AccountNumber")        
.setSortOrder(SortOrder.asc)
.setPager("pagerAccountList")
.setPgButtons(true)

// render the html
.Render()
)
```

**Why I asked this Question :**

Some guys hard coded **grid models** inside **controller** or used **data annotations**. I think this is not a good approach. This way we are tying the view inside logic and this is against MVC rules...

Best Approach is to create a **Html Helper**.

Wish save some hours for someone